# Does core data refresh data model with a delay?

Tags: ios, core-data, fetched-property

I faced with a problem that the core data don't see any changes in my predicate when I'm tryin to modify it. I spent alot of time trying to find why doesn't my fetched property  show me the correct results (see code below) and finally after another coffee break I've seen that  (SUDDENLY!) my fetched property starts to work fine. Is there some delay with updating datamodel? 
Or should I go on breaks more often?

```
-(void)printData{
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"Empl"];
NSError *error;
NSArray *empls = [[self managedObjectContext] executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];

for (NSManagedObject *emplMO in empls){

    NSString *output = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ \n", [emplMO valueForKey:@"emplName"]];
    [self.managedObjectContext refreshObject:emplMO mergeChanges:YES];
    NSArray *allChairs = [emplMO valueForKey:@"allChairs"];
    output = [output stringByAppendingFormat:@" has %d chairs \n", allChairs.count];
    NSLog(@"%@", output);
}
}
```

[image: Here is my model.]

Comment: Two things: (1) How recently were these objects modified? Was it immediately before you call this method? (2) What is the purpose of calling refreshObject:mergeChanges: on an object you just fetched?

Comment: @TomHarrington (1) i've tried few variations: calling 'printData' right after the empl/assets was inserted in cd, and later - after restart application (when the results of 'printData' was wrong, I stop the app then clean it/rebuild it. Next time I launch simulator the results was still incorrect.) I was unable to find any regularity of this problem. It just disappears suddenly. After it disapper, I tried to change the predicate of fetched property (i.e. fetch for all Laptops) but after restart simulator I still got output about Chairs. So I think there is some delay with model refreshing.

Comment: @TomHarrington (2) I thought it can be useful in my case.

Comment: I've just tried to launch my app and it crash with an error `The model used to open the store is incompatible with the one used to create the store`. It happens because I've modified the predicate of fetched property last time I worked with xcode (few hours ago). But I clearly remember that the app didn't crash that last time. It just ignored my modifications that last time.

Comment: If you change the data model, that will happen.

Comment: @TomHarrington Ok I did change data model (fetched property should show me the laptops now) and did reset content and settings in iOS Sim. Then I rebuild the project and run the app. I fill my data (employees and assets) and again I see wrong output when invoke my `printData`. The core data ignoring the changes at this moment and my fetch property shows me the Chairs instead of Laptops.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using single NSManagedObjectContext across your whole app?

from Apple Developer [Reference:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObjectContext_Class/NSManagedObjectContext.html)

> An instance of NSManagedObjectContext represents a single “object space” or scratch pad in an application....Through a context you can retrieve or “fetch” objects from a persistent store, make changes to those objects, and then either discard the changes or—again through the context—commit them back to the persistent store. The context is responsible for watching for changes in its objects and maintains an undo manager so you can have finer-grained control over undo and redo.

Sounds like if you have two contexts, the objects changed in contextA will need to be persisted out to store and back out again for the contextB to see them... UIManagedDocument does autosaving. You may see slight delay/gap in core data update/fetch if you are using 2 or more contexts.

Comment: yes, the MOC is single. My app is a small predicate-training app so I never wanted it to have additional contexts